# Trigger a shiny 'observe' when the dimensions of a data frame change?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to trigger a reactive function (`observe`, `observeEvent`, etc) when the dimensions of a dataframe change? I have tried simply using the dataframe itself as the "x" parameter in `observe`, but this is too sensitive and I end up in a circularity loop.

Comment: Depending on the frame itself works: any dimension changes and therefore value(s) change. Are you able to provide sample code?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

A more robust approach as mentioned by @StéphaneLaurent:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "number_of_rows",
    label = "Number of Rows",
    value = 5L,
    min = 1L,
    max = 100L
  ),
  numericInput(
    inputId = "number_of_columns",
    label = "Number of Columns",
    value = 3L,
    min = 1L,
    max = 100L
  ),
  numericInput(
    inputId = "runif_max",
    label = "runif Maximum",
    value = 1L,
    min = 1L,
    max = 100L
  ),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF_dimensions <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  DF <- reactive({
    DF_tmp <- data.frame(replicate(input$number_of_columns, runif(input$number_of_rows, min = 0, max = input$runif_max)))
    DF_dimensions(dim(DF_tmp))
    DF_tmp
  })
  
  observeEvent(DF_dimensions(), {
    cat(paste("DF_dimensions:", paste(DF_dimensions(), collapse = ", "), "\n"))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({DF()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Initial answer:**

This should get you started:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "number_of_rows",
    label = "Number of Rows",
    value = 5L,
    min = 1L,
    max = 100L
  ),
  numericInput(
    inputId = "number_of_columns",
    label = "Number of Columns",
    value = 3L,
    min = 1L,
    max = 100L
  ),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF <- reactive({
    data.frame(replicate(input$number_of_columns, runif(input$number_of_rows)))
  })
  
  DF_dimensions  <- reactive({dim(DF())})
  
  observeEvent(DF_dimensions(), {
    cat(paste("DF_dimensions:", paste(DF_dimensions(), collapse = ", "), "\n"))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({DF()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It works? Because I would have thought no: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/shinyReactivity.html. I mean it should react to `DF` even if `dim(DF)` does not change.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent please feel free to run the app and test it.

Comment: But this app does not allow to test my point. I know it does not work, in the sense I mentionned.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent now (after all) I took the time to address the non-existent issue with my previous answer ;-).. Joking aside thanks for the heads up - the approach you implied is less prone to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I was wondering whether this way is working as desired. Now I know.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent do you know if this behaviour is "officially" documented somewhere? Currently I'm not aware of any Posit/RStudio article mentioning it.

Comment: Nope, just on my blog and in some Github issues.